# where can I find the catalog for stanford coreNlp depency types

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford CoreNlp lib. I am able to see the parse tree with all the nodes. I was able to look up most of the dependency types, but what is an 'S' node? I can't find the definition any where.

Answer (score 0):

found it. it means simple declarative clause.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.9.8216&rep=rep1&type=pdf